# How to create mutually exclusive fields in Pydantic

Tags: pydantic

I am using Pydantic to model an object. How can I make two fields mutually exclusive?

For instance, if I have the following model:

```
class MyModel(pydantic.BaseModel):
    a: typing.Optional[str]
    b: typing.Optional[str]
```

I want field `a` and field `b` to be mutually exclusive. I want only one of them to be set. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Do you want to allow both fields to be `None`? Please edit the question to clarify this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use pydantic.validator decorator to add custom validations.

```python
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    a: Optional[str]
    b: Optional[str]

    @validator("b", always=True)
    def mutually_exclusive(cls, v, values):
        if values["a"] is not None and v:
            raise ValueError("'a' and 'b' are mutually exclusive.")

        return v
```

Comment: This code is incorrect when `v is not None and bool(v) is False`. `MyModel(a='', b='')` doesn't raise the expected error.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the the [pydantic](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/522#issuecomment-829491002) repo, these seems like a more generic solution:

```py
from typing import Dict, Any, Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, root_validator

class HelloWorldModel(BaseModel):
   foo: Optional[str] = Field(title="foo")
   boo: Optional[str] = Field(title="boo")

@root_validator()
def validate(cls, values: Dict[str, Any]) -> Dict[str, Any]:
    if values.get("foo") and values.get("boo"):
        raise ValueError("Expected only one, either `foo` or `boo`, not together")
     return values
```

Comment: There are issues with this solution. See the linked Github thread